# How to run an if statement only one time per day an if it is TRUE on Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I made a project that measure the temperature and if temperature is too high Arduino call a number or text a message. But if temp is too high I want to notify the person one or two time not every single time. I have RTC but prefer a solution without RTC. Also this microcontroller would run for months.
I write this pseudocode as example:

```
void  loop() {
  int temp = request.temp();
  if (temp > 30) { // Do this once every 24 hours or every some long time if it is true
    send_sms(6985XXXXXX, "Temp is over 30C");
    call(6985XXXXXX);
  }

}
```

Comment: The question is rather if the Arduino has a reliable real-time clock, which I doubt. Depending on how accurate your clock oscillator is, it will drift over time. Typically microcontroller oscillators (particularly simple RC ones) are not accurate enough for this, so you use separate RTC circuitry.

Comment: Well down-vote is for what ? I have RTC but I would like a solution without RTC. How much will it drift?  I dont mind about minutes I just want to not spam with message every sec

Comment: (I did not down vote.) Your oscillator has a specified accuracy, usually expressed in +/- ppm, which is just an obfuscated way of writing percent. If you take this as a percentage of your total time, you can calculate the oscillator drift for the given time period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `millis` function. Be careful of 2 issues:

1. it returns 32-bit values, they overflow every 2^32 milliseconds;
2. ensure you write integer constants correct (e.g. `0xAABBCC` is compiled to a 16-bit `0xBBCC` signed int, there must be `0xAABBCCul`).

The first one follows that you need to operate with time difference, not absolute values. Like this:

```
unsigned long passedTime = millis() - prevWatchTime;
if (passedTime > 1UL * 24UL * 60UL * 60UL * 1000UL) // 1 day
    ...
prevWatchTime = millis();
```

---

It should be combined with flags:

```
const unsigned long sleepTime = 1UL * 24UL * 60UL * 60UL * 1000UL;  // 1 day
bool messageIsSent = false;
unsigned long sendTime;

void loop()
{
    unsigned long passedTime = millis() - sendTime;
    if (passedTime > sleepTime)
        messageIsSent = false;

    if (<must send message> && !messageIsSent) {
        <send message>
        messageIsSent = true;
        sendTime = millis();
    }
}
```

This can correctly prevent messages send up to almost 25 days. As you can check, overflow doesn't affect to difference less than 2^31. E.g. if `x = 2^32 - 1`, `y = x + 101 ~ 100`, then `y - x = 101` even after overflow.

Note that the flag is necessary and cannot be exchanged to direct `millis() - sendTime` check.

Comment: I want to run this sensors for months and years so i will have problem with overflow. How can I fix overflow ?

Comment: @Dimitris Oh, why you don't want to think? Edited the answer.

Comment: @iotXXI can you avoid the overflow by doing this https://www.norwegiancreations.com/2018/10/arduino-tutorial-avoiding-the-overflow-issue-when-using-millis-and-micros/

Comment: @rfii I see there the same solution. Just check differences, not absolute values. Of course it works if the differences are less than 2^31 (maybe 2^32 if they are always positive, not sure).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's supported by Arduino, but a naive solution could be to use [`time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) to get a time-stamp, and don't resend while the current time-stamp is less than 24 hours since the last message was sent. The last time the message was sent is stored in a variable, and compared to the current time-stamp returned by [`time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time).

This naive solution doesn't handle summer/winter time switches very well, and there could be other corner cases it won't handle well too.

If there's no support for the [`time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) function, the Arduino API must have some similar feature to return the current time that could be used instead. Also note that the "current time" doesn't actually have to be an actual "current time" but can be a run-counter from the start of the system.

Comment: There is no STL in Arduino + avr-gcc.

Comment: @ilotXXI How about standard C [`time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) function?

Comment: there is no OS and no RTC clock in Arduino. The only time-related thing is a processor clock counter. And it is available with `millis` and `micros` functions.

Answer (score 2):

Following you can find your code.
What I did is to measure the temperature. The first time that the temperature is too high it gives an allarm. You can have a second allarm only after {Period_ms_1day}. So you can set this variable as you prefer to achieve your purposes:

```
unsigned long Period_ms_1day = 86400000; //time in milliseconds = (60s * 60m *24h*1000) = 1 day
unsigned long prec_event = millis()-Period_ms_1day; 
unsigned long counter;


void  loop() 
{
    temp = request.temp();
    if (temp > 30) 
    { // Do this once every 24 hours or every some long time if it is true
    counter = millis();
        if(counter - prec_event > Period_ms_1day)
        {
           send_sms(6985XXXXXX, "Temp is over 30C");
           call(6985XXXXXX);
           prec_event=millis();

        }
    }
}
```